# Fixing the responsive position of submit button within the input field

Tags: html, css, forms, button, input

I'm trying to keep the position of the submit button ***responsive*** by making it consistently fixed within the input field. It mostly looks fine below the resolution of 1440px but when I start to increase the resolution of the screen, its not responsive at all because the button literally remains at the same position on the page and it doesn't stay within and follow the position of input field as the screen resolution scales.

For your visual reference, this is the design images I'm working towards to: [design image for desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxyNK.jpg), [design image for mobile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ka6AF.jpg).

Here is the link to this project I'm working on my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/GeekyB/pen/OJMjxjb).

And here's the code I'm working with:

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 8%;
  position: relative;
}

.email-field {
  border: 0;
  padding: 0 5%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid hsla(0, 16%, 70%, .5);
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-family: "Josefin Sans", sans-serif;
  background: transparent;
}

.email-field:focus {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px hsl(0, 93%, 68%);
}

#submit-btn {
  width: 90px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 80%, 86%), hsl(0, 74%, 74%));
  background-color: hsl(0, 74%, 74%);
  outline: none;
  transition: 400ms;
  overflow: visible;
  position: absolute;
  right: -1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.6s;
}

/* HOVER & ACTIVE STATES */
#submit-btn:hover {
  transform: translateX(20px);
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, hsl(0, 100%, 96%), hsl(0, 80%, 86%));
}

#submit-btn:active {
  background: #EE8C8C;
}
```

```html
<form action="/submit.php" method="POST">
  <div>
    <input class="email-field" name="email" type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" placeholder="Your email address...">
    <p class="error-message success-message"></p>
  </div>

  <button id="submit-btn" type="submit">
    <img src="https://assets.codepen.io/4417738/icon-arrow_2.svg" alt="right arrow icon">
  </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use on from `display:inline-flex;` instead of display:flex;

Comment: @Bern  did this helped you?

Comment: Yes it did! I thought the solution was going to be more complicated than just changing it to **`display: inline-block`**. 

Thanks so much and I really appreciate the simple, yet concise solution! I have scoured through Google and I've read countless articles and other forums and still couldn't figure it out, until now :D

Comment: Oops, just realized a typo. I meant `display: inline-flex`.